# Nginx trying to connect to upstream with IP and port 443

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect my domain to another domain but keeping my domain in the URL.

This is my settings:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;
    root /home/redacted/redacted/wwwdir;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example2.com/ID/;
    }

    # Block google
    location = /robots.txt {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
    }

}


# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

But I'm seeing errors like this in my logs:

```
2019/05/31 18:35:48 [crit] 14831#14831: *2415 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14090072:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:bad message type) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: IP, server: example.com, request: "GET /templates/js/jquery.nestable.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://IP:443/ID/templates/js/jquery.nestable.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/admin/index.php"
```

I think the issue here is `upstream:"https://IP:443/ID/templates/js/jquery.nestable.js"`

Why is using IP:443 here?

Comment: Because port 443 is the default port for https. That doesn't matter though. It is not causing you any problem.

Comment: What do you mean is not causing any problem? I assume that whatever was trying to fetch that .js script will fail

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do you mean is not causing any problem? I assume that whatever was trying to fetch that .js script will fail. From what I know is not possible to have a valid certificate for a IP, so how do you think https://ip:443 would pass a handshake?

Comment: It's not trying to make an HTTPS connection by IP address, so that's irrelevant. You specified a hostname. Unless of course the configuration you posted is not what you are actually using.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so why it's giving that error?

Comment: Who knows? You need to look at the error logs on the other server.

Comment: I don't control it

Comment: Eh? Then why are you trying to do this at all?

Comment: because I want to hide domain2 behind my own domain

Comment: They probably blacklisted your IP for abuse, or something similar.

Comment: no they don't care about this. I pay them to give me a web UI, but I want to use that web UI with my domain. they specifically told me to do something like this with my nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a backend/upstream using https, Nginx defaults to using client certificate authentication: it expects you to give it a certificate that has been signed by your upstream certificate (see https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/).

As far as I understand this is not what you want; you only want to secure the communication between Nginx and the upstream, not authenticate/authorize it.

I had the same issue a while ago; if I remember correctly, adding `proxy_ssl_verify off;` next to the `proxy_pass ...` directive fixed it.

Comment: I really just want to proxy https://domain1 to https://domain2